# G1GC compaction within regions

Tags: java, g1gc

As I understand, G1 GC performs evacuation to reclaim heap from both young and old regions, in doing so it indirectly compacts heap (copying live objects from a to-be-collected region to an empty region). Could G1 GC get into a case where there are no fully empty regions left to copy objects to but there is enough fragmented heap in semi-full regions? I wanted to ask, does G1 keeps track of free space within the regions, and does it do compacting within a region?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [HotSpot VM Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/toc.html) says in the [Allocation (Evacuation) Failure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html#allocation_evacuation_failure) section:

> If a free (empty) region cannot be found during the evacuation of a region being garbage collected, then an allocation failure occurs (because there is no space to allocate the live objects from the region being evacuated) and a stop-the-world (STW) full collection is done.

This implies, though not stated explicitly, that the STW full collection is capable of performing compacting, as otherwise, it wouldn’t be a cure for the fragmentation problem. I only found an indirect hint about compacting capabilities in the section about [Humongous Objects and Humongous Allocations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc_tuning.html#humongous):

> To reduce copying overhead, the humongous objects are not included in any evacuation pause. A full garbage collection cycle compacts humongous objects in place.

This does not imply that “G1 keeps track of free space within the regions”, as that would defeat the purpose of performing copying by default, but rather, this necessary information will likely be acquired during the full collection, as part of the process.

Comment: it absolutely strikes me recently of how much little information about such interesting topics are to be found online. after two days in the `G1` source code, I am almost confident that you are correct. Even though the liveness and sizes in a certain region are very well known to every GC cycle, so in theory, this is possible.

Comment: @Eugene usually, there’s a difference between the general information about the garbage ratios of the regions, which is needed to select the regions with the most garbage, and the detailed information about the gaps between the still reachable objects within a region. The latter is not needed for a copying collector, which is one of the advantages of the copying collector. So it’s straight-forward to avoid maintaining that information as long as possible.

Comment: you are right and I understand that, this is even implied by the presence of `G1ReservePercent`...

Answer (score -2):

> when will be G1 ( Garbage Collector) starts running and in which memory area it collect first?

The pile is divided into a lot of equivalent estimated pile areas, each a touching scope of virtual memory. Certain district sets are allocated similar jobs (eden, survivor, old)

G1 plays out a simultaneous worldwide stamping stage to decide the liveness of items all through the pile. After the imprint stage finishes, G1 knows which districts are for the most part unfilled. It gathers in these districts first, which as a rule yields a lot of free space. This is the reason this strategy for trash assortment is called Garbage-First. As the name proposes, G1 concentrates its assortment and compaction movement on the regions of the stack that are probably going to be loaded with reclaimable articles, that is, trash. G1 utilizes an interruption forecast model to meet a client characterized stop time target and chooses the quantity of locales to gather dependent on the predetermined respite time target.

The locales distinguished by G1 as ready for recovery are trash gathered utilizing clearing. G1 duplicates objects from at least one locales of the store to a solitary district on the stack, and in the process the two compacts and opens up memory. This departure is performed in parallel on multi-processors, to diminish stop times and increment throughput. In this manner, with every trash assortment, G1 consistently attempts to decrease fracture, working inside the client characterized delay times. This is past the ability of both the past techniques.

> Basically, The amount of live data in each region is tracked, and when
>   a collection is triggered the G1GC will clear the ones with the most
>   ‘garbage’ first.

This means it can collect garbage from semi-full regions as well.